# Can anyone tell me anything about what's being said in the inscriptions and seals on this painting?

Tags: translation, meaning, characters, character-identification

**This is a color and ink painting measuring approx. 15 x 19 inches. I think the script could be referring to the "Tian Shan" mountains but I'm not sure and I think the seal in the lower left starts out with the character for "Qing" but not sure. Any help would be deeply appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvW3J.png)

[image]

Comment: The paining is titled "桂林山水甲天下" (the mountains and waters in Guilin are the best of the world). It's painted （写, short for 写意, which is a type of Chinese painting）in 庚午 year. Depending on it age, it could be year 1990, 1930, ...

Comment: Are you saying that the seal in the lower left does not include the artist signature?

Comment: No, I can't read the seal script. I only commented on the title on the upper-right corner.

Comment: That's okay.  Thanks for your interest and your input.  Let me know if you come up with anything on the seal script.

Comment: The left seal on the top right looks like "张". I have no idea what others are about.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gift that a person receives when he reaches his birthday. Usually it is received when a person reaches 60, 79, 80, 90, 100.. such a full ten lifespan. Because the black character on the far left is a traditional Chinese character “寿”.

[image: This is traditional Chinese character "寿"]

The person giving the gift was from Guilin City, Guangxi Province, or the person who has reached the birthday was located in Guilin City, Guangxi Province. Because on the far right of the picture is written "桂林山水甲天下", which means that the scenery of Guilin is the most beautiful in the world. The scenery of Guilin is very beautiful, even US President Bill Clinton has visited it. In the picture, the sails on the boat are full of wind, which wishes this  man smooth sailing.

On the other boat, a fishman was fishing, and there were four cormorants (a kind of bird) on his clothes. This is just the scenery of Guilin. Chinese people generally believe that even numbers are auspicious and odd numbers are unlucky. So there are two boats and four cormorants. The lower right corner is bamboo, which means that this person has a good character and is respected by others.

This is a birthday painting, expressing blessings. The painting was supposed to be given away in 1990. Because of a cycle of 60 years, the year of Gengwu belongs to the horse, which is 1930, 1990, 2050... . This painting is obviously painted in modern times, that is, in 1990, on a certain person's birthday, the other three people gave him this painting together, because there are three red stamps. One of them is surnamed Zhang（张）, because there is a red badge that is Zhang.